# Time Wait Inside Method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, while-loop

I never worker too much with timers and delays, so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something really really ugly with my code but I can't figure out a solution.

Ok... I have a class called AnimatorsPool, which contains and handles a lot of Animator classes at once. Animator is just a simple, timer based, control mover.

```
    public sealed class AnimatorsPool : IDisposable
    {
        private Boolean m_Disposed;
        private Boolean m_Stopped;
        private Boolean m_Waiting;
        private Int32 m_DelayBetween;
        private Int32 m_DelayStart;
        private List<Animator> m_Animators;
        private Stopwatch m_Stopwatch;

        public Boolean AnimationsFinished
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (Animator animator in m_Animators)
                {
                    if (!animator.AnimationFinished)
                        return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        public AnimatorsPool(Int32 delayBetween, Int32 delayStart)
        {
            m_Disposed = false;
            m_Stopped = false;
            m_Waiting = false;
            m_DelayBetween = ((delayBetween < 0) ? 0 : delayBetween);
            m_DelayStart = ((delayStart < 0) ? 0 : delayStart);
            m_Animators = new List<Animator>();
        }

        private void Wait(Int32 delay)
        {
            m_Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            m_Waiting = true;

            while (!m_Stopped && (m_Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds <= delay))
                Application.DoEvents();

            m_Waiting = false;

            m_Stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        public void Add(Animator animator)
        {
            m_Animators.Add(animator);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!m_Disposed)
            {
                foreach (Animator animator in m_Animators)
                    animator.Dispose();

                m_Animators.Clear();
                m_Animators = null;

                m_Disposed = true;
            }

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (m_Animators.Count > 0)
            {
                if (m_DelayStart > 0)
                    Wait(m_DelayStart);

                m_Animators[0].Start();

                if (m_Animators.Count > 1)
                {
                    for (Int32 i = 1, length = m_Animators.Count; i < length; ++i)
                    {
                        if (m_DelayBetween > 0)
                            Wait(m_DelayBetween);

                        m_Animators[i].Start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            m_Stopped = true;

            while (m_Waiting)
                Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

Inside my main form, which is sometimes using AnimatorsPool, I use the following code:

```
        using (AnimatorsPool pool = new AnimatorsPool(100, (delayAction ? 100 : 0)))
        {
            m_AnimatorsPools.Add(pool);

            for (Int32 i = (controlsCount - 1); i >= 0; --i)
            {
                Animator animator = new Animator(controls[i], coordinates[i], 50);
                pool.Add(animator);
            }

            pool.Start();

            while (!pool.AnimationsFinished)
                Application.DoEvents();

            m_AnimatorsPools.Remove(pool);
        }
```

Ok now... what happened in the beginning was that, if I exited the program while AnimatorsPool was still running Wait() method, my main form was disappearing but the process was still running undefinately in my task manager because of that.
So I implemented a Dispose override in my main form:

```
    protected override void Dispose(Boolean disposing)
    {
        if (!m_Disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                s_RandomProvider.Dispose();

                foreach (AnimatorsPool pool in m_AnimatorsPools)
                    pool.Dispose();

                m_AnimatorsPools.Clear();
                m_AnimatorsPools = null;
            }

            m_Disposed = true;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Ok... now my program exits properly sometimes, but sometimes not. And what I can see from debug is that, when it happens, it's because some AnimatorsPool is still running the Wait() method even if m_Stopped is set to true.
I think I should use threads, timers or something like that, but I've no experience. Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't do this:

```
while (!m_Stopped && (m_Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds <= delay))
    Application.DoEvents();
```

You should use timers and event-driven for this, instead of busy-waiting. That is only ever OK in embedded real-time stuff.

You need to rewrite your code pretty much, and it is difficult to give you pointers without creating a lesson in timers and event-driven development.

**EDIT:** From the `Application.DoEvents` documentation in MSDN *(emphasis mine)*:

> Calling this method causes the current thread to be suspended while all waiting
>   window messages are processed. If a message causes an event to be triggered, then
>   other areas of your application code may execute. **This can cause your application
>   to exhibit unexpected behaviors that are difficult to debug.** If you perform
>   operations or computations that take a long time, it is often preferable to
>   perform those operations on a new thread. For more information about asynchronous
>   programming, see [Asynchronous Programming Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx).

Comment: Should I split my Start method in order to use two Timers with Tick event?

Comment: Edited to add some more info.